# Prompt user for sudo password to run shell command via tkinter GUI and python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, tkinter, terminal

**Scenario**:
I have a tkinter window that has a button and an entry box for a password,
when the button is pressed it will run a command to perform the following

```
sudo apt install mc -y
```

the code runs and works as expected.
However I do not want the password to be promoted via the terminal.

**Goal**
I would like the sudo password to be prompted via the tkinter gui

**Question**

1. Should I use the entry control on the window to collect the password. and pass that to the subprocess. How would you do that? I have not found any clear examples for sudo.
2. Should I take  a different approach?

**Code Snippet**

```
import os
import subprocess as sp
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk

#Window Setup
win = ThemedTk(theme ='clam')
win.geometry('500x400')

#function
def example():
    sp.call (["sudo", "-S", "apt", "install", "mc", "-y"])

#button    
btn = ttk.Button(win,text="Begin Test ",command=example)
btn.place(x=180, y=320, height= 30, width=150)

#password Textbox
pwdtxt = ttk.Entry(win, show="*")
pwdtxt.place(x=180, y=350, height= 30, width=150)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: there are clear examples on how to use `Entry` widget, then simply pass the value to the `sp.call()` list as a variable in the place you need'

Comment: It is not recommended to pass the password in a command line because it will be recorded in shell command history log and also expose the password to other users in process list.